# Using normalize.css file to normalize the css effect in cross browser

Tags: css

While moving on web I found normlize.css can be used to persist the css effect in various browser.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/2.1.3/normalize.css

There are two approach to use it:

Approach 1: use normalize.css as a starting point for your own project’s base CSS, customising the values to match the design’s requirements.

Approach 2: include normalize.css untouched and build upon it, overriding the defaults later in your CSS if necessary.

I think 2nd is easy. 
Does it mean including this css untouched and then working with our css in normal way, correct?

Comment: considering ur leaning towards approach 2, reset.css might be a better fit for u. => http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: did you used it? to use it we just need to include it in our file and then proceed with my css practive. right?

Comment: On their site they dont write clearly how to use it!

Comment: u can do either or. there are CDNs that include certain resets (especially the YUI one), however I personally just copied the code at the top of my CSS. it saves another link call, and allows you to "trim it down" to the elements in your project that are affected (if you wanted to).

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: thanks buddy. But it does not need to make change in my existing css code na?

Comment: naw the whole point of CSSReset is to remove browser-specific layouts and bring it back to a pure state that is the same on all browsers. you put that reset first, then build on it with your own CSS, guaranteeing cross-browser likeness.